# How to combine two java8 stream operations - one terminal and one lazy - into a single operation?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

I'm doing some "algebra" of Java 8's streams, that is, I'm trying to code a simple operation Op that takes two streams as inputs and yields another stream as a result.

So I have this simple code whose aim is to print the secund highest value in a serie of numbers :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SecundHighestValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //setting the input parameters
        int [] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1};

        IntStream S1 = Arrays.stream(numbers);
        IntStream S2 = Arrays.stream(new int[] {Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt()} );

        // setting the operation
        IntStream S3 = S1.filter(x-> x != S2.toArray()[0]); // doesn't work

        /*** does work  ***
        int  maxNumber = S2.toArray()[0];
        IntStream S3 = S1.filter(x-> x != maxNumber);
        */

        // accessing the operation's result stream S3
        int secundMaxNumber = S3.max().getAsInt();
        System.out.println("the secund highest value in the serie " +
                    Arrays.toString(numbers) + " is " + secundMaxNumber);   
    }
}
```

This program won't work, unless I split the one-line operation this way :

```
    int  maxNumber = S2.toArray()[0];
    IntStream S3 = S1.filter(x-> x != maxNumber);
```

Keeping the operation in one line will raise this exception :

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
...*

I understand that it's related to the filter() method's inherent laziness.
The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) explains :

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate (Stream-producing) operations and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations. Intermediate operations are always lazy.

and in fact, the stack trace shows that the operation doesn't execute until I try to access its result in the next line.

Is this behaviour a flawed desing in java8 ? Is it a bug ? And most important, how can I keep the operation in one line and have it work ?

Comment: No, it's the documented and expected behavior. You can consume a stream only once. Not all operations should be on one line. Why do you pass a stream containing a single value nstead of passing the value in the first place?

Comment: @JB Nizet I need to have an operation of "associative" nature (i.e.receving two same type arguments, and outputing same type result). Those associative operations are the only ones allowed for the `reduce` methods, and when you chain operations, you frequently come to use the `reduce` method as part of this holy trinity `filter`, `map`, `reduce`.

Comment: Bojan's explanation made me realize, that java stream's very nature of "short living" objects disallow to "make algebra" with them, (i.e. applying on two streams an operation that would yield another stream) in a sensed way. For the problem given, findind the secund highest number in a serie, Holger's answer is the way to go : efficient and implemented using the java streams philosophy.

Comment: And to whom it may interest, here's my 1-line version of the answer. Not super efficient (3 streams are used which is better than O(n^2)), but one and only one line of code. Stupid but fun ;-) : `return Arrays.stream(Arrays.stream(tab).mapToObj(x-> new int[] {x}).reduce( new int[] { tab[0], Arrays.stream(tab).max().getAsInt() }, (a, b) -> new int[] { (a[0] == a[1]) ? b[0] : (b[0] == a[1]) ? a[0] : Math.max(a[0], b[0]), a[1] } ) ).reduce((a,b)-> (a==b) ? OptionalInt.empty().getAsInt() : a).getAsInt();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this does not work:

```
IntStream S3 = S1.filter(x-> x != S2.toArray()[0]);
```

is because S2 can only be acted on once.  and filter recalculates it for every entry in S3.

Think of it filter as a for loop, and s2 as a value that can be only ready once.
You can compare streams to System.in - once you read the value once you cannot re-read it.  You have to get a new one.

A bit more information:
The operation is not lazy since you have this line of code which makes it terminal:

```
secundMaxNumber = S3.max().getAsInt();
```

Side note: to get the Xth maxNumber, you can also just do: you do not need to use the stream multiple times.

```
S1.sorted().limit(x).skip(x-1).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

References:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-

Comment: Bojan, your explanation is helpful and very clear, nonetheless, the `sorted()` operation may be problematic from an efficiency point of view : I don't know how sorting a serie compares to searching the serie twice (1st time: max number, 2nd time : the serie being filtered, max number is now the secund max).

Comment: with streams, this should be optimal.  Since the sorted() is not going to do any work until a terminal operation, and since we have limit(x) it will actually not sort the whole stream, it will just get the limit values. 

On a side note, programming should not having magic numbers.  E.g. find the second number should not be a function, instead findXthLargestNumber ( int valueToFind)

Comment: @Bojan Petkovic: the `limit` and `skip` operations apply to the *sorted* elements, which implies that you have to know the sorted order to choose the right elements. In theory, the lazy nature allows a `Stream` implementation to recognize the combination of `sorted` and subsequent `limit`/`skip` to understand that this is a search for the n’th or last n’th element, but this doesn’t happen in practice (with the current implementation). So this will always sort all elements…

Comment: @Bojan, you're right for programming that shouldn't be incorporating magic numbers in code, that's not really the case here, I'm indeed searching for the secund highest value, but no magic numbers in the code. on [this link](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) you can see that sorting algorithms can be very expensive. Ho ! and I have forgotten to say thanks for your explanation : I finally understood my mistake thanks to it !

Comment: By the way, this code returns the x’th number in natural order, not the “x’th maxNumber”. If you want the semi-biggest value, you have to know the stream’s size in advance to calculate the right `x`.

Comment: @Holger is correct, streams at the moment are not smart enough to realize they only need to find the first element.  or do limits

Depending on your expected list size you should decide how to get the second largest value.

Comment: You won this question Bojan ;-) however I think the code provided by Holger is better from a few perspectives : efficiency first, and secund, doing the job the right way. However, your explanation took my mind out of its confusion and explained my mistake in a very clear way. So thank you and know that you're a lucky guy : you won my answer flipping a coin heads or tails, no kidding.

Answer (score 6):

If streaming over the source is possible and not expensive, like with arrays, you may just stream twice, like in [azro’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721930/2711488):

```
int maxNumber = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();
int secondMaxNumber = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(x-> x != maxNumber).max().getAsInt();
```

If streaming twice isn’t possible or expensive, you need a custom collector to get the second largest value efficiently, i.e. with holding only the necessary two values. E.g.

```
final class SecondMax {
    long max=Long.MIN_VALUE, semi=max;

    void add(int next) {
        if(next>semi) {
            if(next>max) {
                semi=max;
                max=next;
            }
            else if(next<max) {
                semi=next;
            }
        }
    }
    void merge(SecondMax other) {
        if(other.max>Long.MIN_VALUE) {
            add((int)other.max);
            if(other.semi>Long.MIN_VALUE) add((int)other.semi);
        }
    }
    OptionalInt get() {
        return semi>Long.MIN_VALUE? OptionalInt.of((int)semi): OptionalInt.empty();
    }
}
```

With this helper, you can get the value in a single stream operation:

```
OptionalInt secondMax = Arrays.stream(array)
  .collect(SecondMax::new, SecondMax::add, SecondMax::merge).get();
```

Comment: I hesitated between your answer and Bojan's one. I did not know how to decide so I flipped a coin heads or tails (and Bojan's won). Someone said once "identifying the ailment is half its cure", what Bojan's did by giving me a clear explanation of my mistake. You gave the secund half: the medicine. Thanks for your very pretty and "zen" snippet Holger and sorry for not having the ability to split my choice between the two of you.

Answer (score 2):

You have four lines :

```
 IntStream S1 = Arrays.stream(numbers);
 IntStream S2 = Arrays.stream(new int[] {Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt()} );
 int  maxNumber = S2.toArray()[0];
 IntStream S3 = S1.filter(x-> x != maxNumber);
 int secundMaxNumber = S3.max().getAsInt();
```

Same in 2 :

```
int  maxNumber = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();
int secundMaxNumber = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(x-> x != maxNumber).max().getAsInt();
```

It's hard to re-use streams so better to do it in one-way, and better calculate the max in a variable and re-use to not calculate it each time

Comment: Azro, your solution is elegant but problematic : you re-calculate the serie's max for each element in the stream. The max number won't change so there's no need to recalculate it (series.length) times. That is, O(n^2) in big O notation.

Comment: @bistrot oh yes, on this small example it does not have effect but you're right, i changed

Answer (score 1):

Since the input is an int array, The solution provided by @azro is good enough to me. just second @Holger: don't have to define a new class:

```
final Supplier<int[]> supplier = () -> new int[] { Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
final ObjIntConsumer<int[]> accumulator = (a, i) -> {
    if (i > a[0]) {
        a[1] = a[0];
        a[0] = i;
    } else if (i != a[0] && i > a[1]) {
        a[1] = i;
    }
};

int secondMax = Arrays.stream(nums).collect(supplier, accumulator, (a, b) -> {})[1];
```

Or with the API provided in third-party library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
int secondMax = IntStream.of(nums).distinct().kthLargest(2).get();
```

Comment: Long story in short... I'm here to try to provide the best answer by my knowledge. I may have the intention to promote the work we have done. but only when it's the right&best answer. in other words, I will do the extract thing regardless i'm the author/contributor or not. if any answer is judged by who wrote it, not itself here.  that will be funny to me.

Comment: Thanks for this nice piece of code however theres' one important trouble with it : when there is no secund max at all (e.g. `int [] nums =  {3};`  or `int [] nums = {2, 2, 2};`), I get this output : _the secund highest value in the serie is -2147483648_. @Holger 's snippet handles this case better, it raises a _java.util.NoSuchElementException_.

Comment: However, your implementation with AbacusUtil is fine : it will cope with the "no secund max" cases correctly raising the same _java.util.NoSuchElementException_ as @Holger's code does. One small thing that I dislike, the need to insert the `distinct()`, when I drop it, it returns the max number :-( . This should be explicitly documented in your [API doc](http://www.landawn.com/api-docs/com/landawn/abacus/util/stream/IntStream.html#kthLargest-int-) or better, be corrected. But nice job, nonetheless !

Comment: You should never provide a non-working merge function like `(a, b) -> {}`. This might work with the current implementation when using a sequential stream, but leaves a time bomb in your code. Besides that, your variant doesn’t handle streams correctly when there is no second max value, e.g. when the stream is empty or has only a single element. You can’t even tell apart whether there is no second max value or whether `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the actual second max value, e.g. with the input `{ MIN_VALUE, 42 }`.